# Spellcheck for Textarea not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a spell check for a textarea. The way i want it as soon as the element is loaded, it shall show all typos with red lines below them.

However the textarea in my example at http://jsfiddle.net/codejedi/JShpZ/56/ gets the spellcheck invoked only when i press spacebar at the end of textarea text.

I tried getting the focus to textarea using the code below, still that does not works for me,

```
var ta = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
ta[0].focus();
```

I have also tried spellcheck=true attribute inside textarea.

An example i have checked had this kind of feature where element load showed all typos with red lines below them.

I may want to use pure Javascript.

Comment: Why would focusing on an element help? What browser are you using? It's not supported in IE9 or below

Comment: I read somewhere, spellcheck invokes on element focus. I am using Firefox 26, Chrome 32 Mac OS X, Fx/Chrome on Windows 7

Comment: I tested your fiddle in Chrome `Version 32.0.1700.102 m` there spellcheck is invoked on page load and the red line is shown.